# Compare columns with time datatype in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have table with column with time Datatype.I want to compare the time in SQL.The main problem is when i compare any time with '00:00:00'/'00:10:00'.

For e.g.  select timings from train where trn_time > '19:00:00'.
then in output i want '00:00:00' also wic I am not getting.
And I dont want to use 'Datetime' data type. 
Please help.

Comment: Can you add some sample data and expected results please? I don't understand your narrative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i created a table in mysql with name 'table11'

```
CREATE TABLE `table11` (
    `id` INT(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `time_col` TIME NULL DEFAULT NULL
)
```

and inserted data as follows [image]

and when i used following query

```
select  * from table11 tbl where tbl.time_col< '19:00:00'
```

i got result

[image]

if you use tbl.time_col< '19:00:00' then only you will get '00:00:00' in the output. 
i think in your case its better to use 'Datetime' datatype

Comment: no but aftr 19:00:00,20:00:00.....23:00:00,00:00:00 comes no.So for the condition timing > '19:00:00'.I should get 00:00:00 in output.

Comment: @KT.. - if you use timing < '19:00:00' then only you will get  '00:00:00' in the output.

Comment: @KT.. - i think in your case its better to use 'Datetime' datatype

Comment: See i have table name train.in this there is one column in which I want to store time of the train.So it will make no sense in storing date and time of the train using DateTime Data Type.So I have used only Time data type.But now I am facing problem with comparing time.

Comment: @KT.. 00:00:00 is less than  '19:00:00'